# How do I open Material-UI Modal on top of clicked-button?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a button that when clicked, opens a Material-UI Modal. Using the getModalStyle can set it to a particular location:

```
 function getModalStyle() {
    const top = "50";
    const left = 50;
  
    return {
      top: `${top}%`,
      left: `${left}%`,
      transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
    };
  }
```

How do I have it automatically open on top of the button that clicked it?

Thank you,

Comment: That won't be a modal anymore. That will be a [Popover](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/)

Comment: ah ok, thank you! If you specify that as the answer, I will mark it as resolved. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm good. Good luck with your coding.